# why the slice variable does not get overwritten when assigned over and over?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

```
func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(s)

    // Slice the slice to give it zero length.
    s = s[:0]
    printSlice(s)

    // Extend its length.
    s = s[:4]
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

In this program, why the value of variable `s` does not get overwritten when reassigned again and again?

Why when we extend its length from `0` to `4` it still holds the underlying values at the same index?

Edit: I read slice internals as suggested, and I understand that slices are mere views to the underlying array, however, my question is that instead of using `s1, s2, s3` variable names, when only `s` is used over and over, internally what is happening and why the same variable is not overwritten?

Comment: Please read [slice internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) to understand how slices work.

Comment: @Marc Sorry, that doesn't answer clearly enough for me, I read that slices are references to arrays so changes made will affect the underlying array. I was more of confused with using the same variable that is being assigned multiple times, yet remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

That has to do with how slices work in Go. Basically, a slice is a data structure containing three things:

1. A pointer to a backing array.
2. A length (the number of elements in the array which are "in-use").
3. A capacity (the total number of indexes in the backing array (arrays are fixed size)).

What you're doing when you write `s = s[:0]` is creating a new slice with a pointer to the **same backing array** but with a different length. When you later write `s = s[:4]` it is, again, the same backing array, so the elements hidden by `s[:0]` are still present.